# Name of blob after uploading from memorystream

Tags: asp.net, arrays, azure-blob-storage, memorystream

I want to upload a dynamically created excel file to blob. The file is in the form of a byte array. This is what im doing.

```
bytes = package.GetAsByteArray();
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("constring");
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("excelcontainer");
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("excelblob");
 using (MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream(bytes))
 {
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(ms);
 }
```

Now how do I get the blobname for this blob which was just uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the name do you not?

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("excelblob");
```

The name here should be the name of the blob.

Comment: thats a container. i want to access what i just uploaded.

Comment: excelcontainer has multiple files

Comment: No, that's the blob reference, the container is the line above. You name the blob reference whatever you want to call it.